# Can't install pod in iOS app with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am not able to successfully install pods to my project. I am always getting this error:

[image]

This is my Podfile (I added FirebaseFirestoreSwift but even when I undo the changes, its still not working):

[image]

It was working fine a month ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the latest version of Xcode command line tools using `xcode-select --install`. If you already have an installed version, you might get an error similar to

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

In that case, try removing the old command line tools from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and reinstall it again.